# how to get string literal from LLVM IR instruction

Tags: llvm-ir

I want to get string literal from LLVM IR.

C source code looked like:

```
char *test = "string";
```

LLVM IR looked like:

```
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [9 x i8] c"string\00", align 1
@test = global i8* getelementptr inbounds ([9 x i8], [9 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), align 8
```

I got some how in `ArgValue` variable. --> the second line of IR.. 
my code looked like this : and now i am stuck after getting Constant*

```
GetElementPtrInst *gep = dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(ArgValue);
Value *Valop = gep->getPointerOperand();
Instruction *inst = dyn_cast<Instruction>(Valop);
Constant *cda = dyn_cast<Constant>(inst->getOperand(0));
```

now after the last statement, how do i get the constant "string" is something i stuck at.
Constant *cda is not null.. the third line is success
it does not work if i try to type cast to any other object.
please help...